# How to import external library with intern js?

Tags: node.js, intern

I'm working on the UI automation of a web app using [internjs](https://theintern.io/intern/#what-is-intern) and I'm trying to dump the test report for functional test into excel file directly. What I want to do is :

1. Create test report of function test in Excel file
2. Take the screenshot if the test fails or skip.
3. Compress(zip) the excel report and screen shot into one zip fie.

In order to do this i need to install third party library [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) .

Now I'm stuck in a very basic problem i.e I'm unable to import the library into my custom reporter. So can some body please help me on how to import the external library intern project.

I installed archiver using following command:
`npm install archiver --save`

My code goes as follows:

```
 define([
    'intern/dojo/node!fs',
     '../TestUtils/ExcelUtil',
     '../TestUtils/SnapShotUtil',
     'archiver'  //<= import archiver
 ], function (fs, ExcelUtil, SnapShotUtil, archiver) {
    var Excel = ExcelUtil.instance();
    var screenshotDir = 'test-reports/screenshot/';
    function TestReporter(config) {
    config = config || {};
}
TestReporter.prototype = {

    suiteError: function (suite) {
        SnapShotUtil.takeSnapShot(suite, suite.name + '-' + suite.error.name)
    },
    testPass: function (test) {
        Excel.addRow([test.parent.name, test.name, 'N/A', 'Pass', 'N/A'])
    },
    testSkip: function (test) {
        var picName = screenshotDir + test.parent.name.replace(/ /g, '') + '-' +
            test.name.replace(/ /g, '') + '.png'
        Excel.addRow([test.parent.name, test.name, 'N/A', 'Skipped', '=HYPERLINK(' + picName + ',ScreenShot)'])
        SnapShotUtil.takeSnapShot(test, picName)

    },

    testFail: function (test) {
        var picName = screenshotDir + test.parent.name.replace(/ /g, '') + '-' +
            test.name.replace(/ /g, '') + '-' + test.error.name + '.png'
        Excel.addRow([test.parent.name, test.name, test.error.name, 'Failed', '=HYPERLINK(' + picName + ',ScreenShot)'])
        SnapShotUtil.takeSnapShot(test, picName)

    }
};
return TestReporter;
```

});

But I'm getting following error:

```
  Error: Failed to load module archiver from 
  D:/Users/sshrestha/Documents/APps/newAuto/advtestautomation/archiver.js 
(parent: Automation/ConfigFiles/TestReporter.js)
  at ReadFileContext.callback  <node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\loader.ts:831:119>
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete]  <fs.js:303:13>
```

And my folder structure goes as follows

[image]

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

archiver is distributed as CommonJS modules, so you'll need to import it using the dojo/node plugin (just like you're doing with 'fs'):

```
intern/dojo/node!archiver
```

Comment: Do you mean we don'n need to install archiver seperately ?

Comment: You still need to install archiver. The issue with with format of the JS modules in the archiver package. The `define([ 'archiver' ], ...)` command will try to load archiver as an AMD module. However, archiver modules use the CommonJS format, so they have to be loaded using a loader plugin, like `define([ 'intern/dojo/node!archiver' ], ...)`.